# Фильтрация+анализ данных

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Задача:
Отфильтруйте все строительные объекты, кроме тех, что на этапе строительства «Котлован» и на этапе «Заморожено». Сколько их в датасете?

Решение:

```
filter = ~(dataset[['Этап строительства']=='Котлован' & dataset['Этап строительства']=='Заморожено'].isin(districts))
filtered_dataset = dataset[filter]
filtered_dataset.head()
```

Строка пишет ошибку:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
301         #  (xint or xbool) and (yint or bool)
\--\> 302         result = op(x, y)
303     except TypeError:

9 frames
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'float'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'bool' and 'str'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/ops/array_ops.py in na_logical_op(x, y, op)
326                     f"Cannot perform '{op.__name__}' with a dtyped \[{x.dtype}\] array "
327                     f"and scalar of type \[{typ}\]"
\--\> 328                 ) from err
329
330     return result.reshape(x.shape)

TypeError: Cannot perform 'rand\_' with a dtyped \[object\] array and scalar of type \[bool\]
```

Вот только не пойму, видимо где-то синтаксис не так завернул. Или что-то еще не так ?

Comment: ну и по вопросу. про какой датасет речь, про какой модуль, где теги, почему все скобки экранированы?

Comment: Как и написано в моём статусе "Я НЕ волшебник" - Я только обучаюсь писать код. Поэтому прошу простить если, что-то не так описал в задаче. У НЕ волшебников так бывает. НО! Я стараюсь...

Answer (score 0):

Много лишнего, в решении, и неоптимальная логика. Попробуйте так:

```
filtered_dataset = dataset[~dataset['Этап строительства'].isin(['Котлован', 'Заморожено'])]
```

Comment: Так я и сам пишу, что как-то сложно получилось у меня!
Однако, Вы иак же в части синтаксиса ничего не упустили ?
Ибо...
>>> File "<ipython-input-69-95ce44f0be92>", line 1
>>>   filtered_dataset = dataset[~dataset['Этап строительства'].isin(['Котлован', 'Заморожено']]
                                                                                         ^
>>> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: вероятно, скобку пропустил. я же пишу без проверки - вы не предоставили тестовых данных. я исправил ответ.

Comment: И все таки Ваше решение не верно.
А вот верное решение:
>>> filter = ~dataset['Этап строительства'].isin(['Котлован', 'Заморожено'])
>>> filtered_dataset = dataset[filter]
>>> filtered_dataset

Comment: Ошибка strawdog в Вашем решении:
вы отрицание в dataset завернули

Comment: @SouStan вы понимаете, что в своем ответе вы просто переписали мое решение, но вместо одной строки у вас - две?

Answer (score 0):

Верное решение моего вопроса:

```
filter = ~dataset['Этап строительства'].isin(['Котлован', 'Заморожено'])
filtered_dataset = dataset[filter]
filtered_dataset
```